# Remove submenu item from list

Tags: php, functions, menus, admin-menu, sub-menu

I have the following script within my `functions.php` file to avoid certain users from modifying things they shouldn't and would like to remove one more item, the *Appearances > Themes* submenu.

```
function remove_menus () {
global $menu;
    $restricted = array(__('Dashboard'), __('Posts'), __('Pages'), __('Comments'), __('Plugins'), __('Users'), __('Tools'), __('Links'), __('Settings'));
    end ($menu);
    while (prev($menu)){
        $value = explode(' ',$menu[key($menu)][0]);
        if(in_array($value[0] != NULL?$value[0]:"" , $restricted)){unset($menu[key($menu)]);}
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
```

How would I be able to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the API functions [`remove_menu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page) and [`remove_submenu_page`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page) to remove menu items rather than manipulating global variables.

This will remove the themes page under appearance:

```
function wpa_remove_themes_submenu() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'themes.php', 'themes.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wpa_remove_themes_submenu', 999 );
```